# Using SceneKit for hitTesting not returning a hit with SCNNode

Tags: swift, scenekit, scnnode

The documentation in XCode clearly states that hitTesting a geometry in SceneKit can be done with SCNRender, SCNView or the SCNNode themselves when one plans to test a 3D line segment.  I have a use for SCNScene with its nodes without a renderer or a view, therefore I am planning to use SCNNode hitTesting.  I  create a SCNScene, put a SCNNode in it and test a simple ray that goes through, but I always get an empty hitList and I don't understand why:

```
import Swift
import SceneKit

let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 1.0, height: 1.0, length: 1.0, chamferRadius: 0)
let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)

var scene = SCNScene()
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

let from = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -2, z: 0)
let to = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 2 , z: 0)

var hits = scene.rootNode.hitTestWithSegmentFromPoint(from, toPoint: to, options:nil) // this is always empty
if hits != nil {
    if hits!.count > 0 {
        var hit = (hits!.first as! SCNHitTestResult).node as SCNNode
    }
}
```

I have tried passing various forms of options but nothing changes.

1. SCNHitTestFirstFoundOnlyKey: yes or no does not change anything
2. SCNHitTestSortResultsKey:  yes or no does not change anything
3. SCNHitTestClipToZRangeKey: invalid for SCNNode
4. SCNHitTestBackFaceCullingKey: yes or no does not change anything
5. SCNHitTestBoundingBoxOnlyKey: yes or no does not change anything
6. SCNHitTestRootNodeKey: rootNOde of scene or boxNode does not change
   anything
7. SCNHitTestIgnoreHiddenNodesKey: yes or no does not change anything

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer, which is either a bug or a feature: using SCNScene and its nodes SCNNode for 3D hitTesting, in particular the method: "hitTestWithSegmentFromPoint(toPoint:options:)" does not return a hit unless the scene is included in an SCNView. It appears it cannot be used offscreen. My guess is yours for why this is the case, although I can imagine it has something to do with performing some of these quite expensive calculations on the graphics card.

I have tested this using the GameView SCNScene starter project.  The critical line is self.gameView!.scene = scene

```
override func awakeFromNib(){
    let scene = SCNScene()
    let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 1.0, height: 1.0, length: 1.0, chamferRadius: 0.0)
    let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)
    boxNode.position=SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

    // create and add a light to the scene
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

    // create and add an ambient light to the scene
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = NSColor.darkGrayColor()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    // set the scene to the view
    // uncomment this to fail
    self.gameView!.scene = scene

    // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    self.gameView!.allowsCameraControl = true

    // show statistics such as fps and timing information
    self.gameView!.showsStatistics = true

    // configure the view
    self.gameView!.backgroundColor = NSColor.blackColor()

    let hitList = scene.rootNode.hitTestWithSegmentFromPoint(SCNVector3(x:-10,y:0,z:0), toPoint: SCNVector3(x:10,y:0,z:0), options:[SCNHitTestBackFaceCullingKey:false, SCNHitTestSortResultsKey:true, SCNHitTestIgnoreHiddenNodesKey:false])

    if hitList?.count > 0 {
        println("Hit found: \n\n\( hitList![0] )") // assign self.gameView!.scene = scene to reach this point.
    } else {
        println("No hit") // uncomment self.gameView!.scene = scene to reach this point.
    }

}
```

Comment: Either it's a bug that SceneKit doesn't work the way you expect, it it's a big that the docs don't say what to expect. [File a report](http://bugreport.apple.com) and we'll find out either way.

Comment: Same in 2020. Not only does the node need to be in an SCNView, but you also need to wait for SceneKit's background process to finish adding it. The actual code in the answer doesn't work for me unless there's a time gap between adding and testing (but that might be because I'm using a more complex model).

Comment: It is expected behaviour, according to the docs "A 2D point in the rendered screen coordinate space can refer to any point along a line segment in the 3D scene coordinate space" so since the scene was not rendered using a SCNView, there is no way to hit test the scene as you have no way of knowing what's behind that 2D point until you render the scene.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had trouble with hitTestWithSegmentFromPoint.

I was calling it in viewDidLoad() and it returned a 0 elements array, though I was sure there was a hit.

Calling it in viewDidAppear() (or later) solved my problem.